# How to use python virtual env in azure webjob

Tags: python, azure, virtualenv, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to set up a python script as an azure webjob and the script is using several external dependencies, and in the documantation there seem to be no reference to using virtual env for webjobs.

how can i set a virtual env for the webjob? preferably without collecting the enviroment locally and running the script thorugh run.cmd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to activate an already existing virtualenv, you can call its activate script. For instance, if you want to activate the web app's virtualenv, you can run

```
/path/to/web-app/env/Scripts/activate.bat
```

to acticate that particular virtulenv.

Comment: yeah but where is the activate script, I want to access the virtualenv that the webapp created for itself during deployment

Comment: In my case (without custom deployment configuration), it was located at: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts". You can cd to that directory and call activate.bat

Comment: It is important to note that, if the webjob is added through the new portal (portal.azure.com), the job is run on the web app's machine, however, if it is added through the old portal (manage.windowsazure.com), the job is run on another machine, and the above approach would not work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and found an answer in [this post](http://nicholasjackson.github.io/azure/python/python-packages-and-azure-webjobs/).

**Short answer** : put the directory of the module you want to include in the ZIP file you upload in the webjob. You can then reference it directly in your code.

Hope that helps!

Comment: its not exactly what i was looking for, there is a way for a python webapp to use virtualenv and i want to replicate this for a webjob. however this is enough for now.

Comment: Understood! Sorry but no idea how to at the moment, I'll get back to you if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of workaround but it works. Just add these lines to web job script.

```
import sys
site_packages = "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\env\\Lib\\site-packages"
sys.path.append(site_packages)
import requests
```